# How do I use regular expressions to match a list of file locations?

Tags: csh

I am trying to make a script that will identify file locations and types based on their file path. For example, If i have a location /home/file/txt/test.txt and /home/file/tcl/test.tcl . I want to make variables that for the third / location. So in the example case this would be txt and tcl. So I will have a list of locations that follow this format. I want to do a foreach through the list and then have a variable be set to the third / location. Then I will print that variable. What would be the correct regexp for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your task is quite vague. It is always good to post desired inputs and outputs.
Anyway here is some startup for Your task if I understood well Your specification:

```
#!/bin/env csh
set dir='./file/'
set types=('tcl' 'txt')
foreach type (${types})
  #HERE replace with Your commands
  #example find with regex
  echo " ... searching for *.${type} in ${dir}${type}/"
  find "${dir}${type}/" -type f -regex '.*\.'"${type}"'$' -print0 | xargs -0 printf "%s\n" 
end

exit 0
```

There is setup of `dir` where to find and array of Your `types`. Foreach loop goes through dir/type and find files with type suffix using regexp. `xargs` is optional here and I place it on purpose in order to show how to handle correctly files. You can replace e.g. with:

```
xargs -0 -I {} cp {} /home/newdestination/
```

If you need to copy to new destination for instance.

Test:

```
% ./list_file.csh
 ... searching for *.tcl in ./file/tcl/
./file/tcl/a.tcl
./file/tcl/b.tcl
 ... searching for *.txt in ./file/txt/
./file/txt/a.txt
./file/txt/b.txt
```